# Rearrange columns in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have data in Google Sheets that I want to rearrange.

In each row, starting from the 4th column onwards, there are repeating column pairs of `Favorite Fruit #`  & `Favorite Color #` where `#` indicates the index of the pair relative to other pairs. For example, `Favorite Fruit 1` and `Favorite Color 1` are followed by `Favorite Fruit 2` and  `Favorite Color 2`, etc.

1. I would like to reorganize the data so that each column pair is in its row.
2. The column pairs in all rows share the same two columns.
3. The first three columns from the original row that contained a particular column pair are repeated on the new rows where that column pair is now located.

I can't figure out how to do it.

For example:

| Date | Class | Name | Fruit 1 | Color 1 | Fruit 2 | Color 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2/27/2024 | Class 1 | Alice | Apple | Red | Grapes | Black |

[image]

Would become:

| Date | Class | Name | Fruit | Color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2/27/2024 | Class 1 | Alice | Apple | Red |
| 2/27/2024 | Class 1 | Alice | Grapes | Black |

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications Stack Exchange. This post is not a good fit for this question-and-answer site, as it looks like a service request rather than a question about a specific problem using a web application.  If you are new to Google Sheets, please review the resources for Google Sheet users provided by Google. You can find them in the Help menu. If you are already familiar with Google Sheets, please provide more details starting by specifying the locale (country) of your spreadsheet. Also provide the sample data as text, instead of as image.

Comment: Consider providing input and expected output as **plain text table** in the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easy to copy/paste**.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question [useless for others](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) or images, which are [hard to copy](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Comment: I edited my formula to make it more efficient and extensible and added an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

## Formula

```
=LET(mRng,A2:C, dByX,2, dRng,D2:G, mCols,COLUMNS(mRng),
   mRows,MAX(FILTER(ROW(mRng), LEN(INDEX(mRng,,1)))),
   idx,TOCOL(MAKEARRAY(mRows, COLUMNS(dRng)/dByX, LAMBDA(r, c, r))),
   mArr,BYROW(idx, LAMBDA(r, INDEX(mRng, r))),  
   dArr,WRAPROWS(TOROW(QUERY(dRng, "LIMIT "&mRows)), dByX),
   qryTxt,JOIN(" OR ", ARRAYFORMULA("Col" & 
     SEQUENCE(1, dByX, mCols+1) & " <> ''")),
   QUERY({mArr,dArr}, "WHERE "& qryTxt))
```

## Explanation

1. The LET function is used to enable the storing of values and intermediary calculations in arbitrarily named variables for reuse.
2. **`mRng`** stores the **meta range** (columns A to C), which contains the values common to each row's column pairs. Width of **`mRng`** can be any non-zero number of columns.
3. **`dByX`** stores the number of **data** columns to group by.  For your column pairs, that would be a group of **`2`**. This variable makes the formula more extensible should your needs change as you could wrap by any number of columns you want.
4. **`dRng`** contains the column groups **data range** (columns D to G in your example). Width can be expanded/contracted to any non-zero multiple of **`dByX`**. For your column pairs, that would be 2, 4, 6, etc.
5. **`mCols`** calculates the column count for **`mRng`**.
6. **`mRows`** returns the number of the last populated row in column 1 of **`mRng`** to be used to constrain the range's:

   1. FILTER is applied to an array of **`mRng`**'s row numbers.
   2. LEN is used for the filter condition to return only those rows that contain a non-zero-length value.
   3. MAX is then applied to the results to return the highest row number.
7. **`idx`** stores a single-column array of row indexes used later to retrieve the correct meta row from **`mRng`**. `idx` is created as follows:

   1. MAKEARRAY is used to create a 3-dimensional array that contains the same number of rows as **`mRows`** and the same number of columns as there are column groups in **`dRng`** using the formula **`COLUMNS(dRng)/dByX`**.

      1. For each position in the new array, MAKEARRAY passes its position (row number and column number), one-by-one, into a LAMBDA function that stores them in **`r`** and **`c`** respectively.
      2. The LAMBDA's formula returns the current row number **`r`** in every position of the array (column number is completely ignored. 
          For example, where **`x`** is any number, if the current position is any of **`R1C1:R1Cx`**  the formula always returns **`1`**, for **`R3C1:R3Cx`** it would be **`3`**, etc. Here is an example 2 x 3 array that MAKEARRAY could return

         ```
         | 1 | 1 | 1 |
         | 2 | 2 | 2 |
         | 3 | 3 | 3 |
         ```
   2. TOCOL is used to transform the 3-dimensional array returned by MAKEARRAY into a single-column array. **`idx`** is now an array of numbers that match the correct row index of **`mRng`** that should go with each new row created from the column groups in **`mRng`**.
8. **`mArr`** returns a **meta array** built using BYROW:

   1. BYROW passes each value from **`idx`**, one-by-one, into a LAMBDA function that stores the current value in **`r`**.
   2. The LAMBDA's formula uses INDEX to return the row in **`mRng`**  whose row index is equal to **`r`**.
   3. This is repeated until BYROW has passed in every value from **`idx`**.
9. **`dArr`** returns a **data array** built using WRAPROWS:

   1. QUERY is first used to constrain the open range **`dRng`** to **`mRows`** using the LIMIT parameter.
   2. The array returned by QUERY is transformed by TOROW to a single row containing all the column groups.
   3. WRAPROWS transforms the single-row into a **`dByX`**-column array by wrapping it after every **`dByX`** columns (2 in your example). For example,
      This row:

      ```
      | Apple | Red | Grape | Blue | Plum | Taupe |
      ```

      Would be wrapped like this:

      ```
      | Apple | Red   |
      | Grape | Blue  |
      | Plum  | Taupe |
      ```
10. Another QUERY will be used to combine the two arrays and remove any rows that don't include a fruit or color (in case the 2nd, 3rd, etc. choices are not required fields). To this end, **`qryTxt`** returns a text string to be used in that final QUERY.  It's created dynamically to allow for different values of **`dByX`**:

    1. SEQUENCE is used to create an array of column numbers starting from column **`mCols+1`** (the first data column after the last meta column), and including **`dByX`** columns. For example, in your example **`mCols=3`** and **`dByX=2`** so the array of column numbers would be **`{4;5}`**. In other words 2 columns, 4 and 5.
    2. Inside an ARRAYFORMULA, **`"Col"`** is prepended to each column number, and **`" <> ''"`** is appended. Transforming the array to **`{"Col4  <> ''";"Col5 <> ''"}`**
    3. JOIN is then used to convert the array to a single text string with each array value now delimited by **`" OR "`**. So, the new text string is:
        **`"Col4  <> '' OR Col5 <> ''"`**
11. The final QUERY combines and returns the **meta** and **data** arrays **`{mArr, dArr}`** using **`qryTxt`** as the query in order to skip any rows that don't have values in at least one of the **data** columns.